# Duplicate message processing using Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka

Tags: duplicates, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka binder. It works great but the client receives duplicate messages. Already tried all of Kafka Consumer Properties with no result.

Check 2 classes in my example of application - AggregateApplication and EventFilterApplication. In case I run EventFilterApplication - have only 1 message, in case for AggregateApplication - 2 same messages.

---

Here is my code below:

**1) Aggregator**

```
import com.example.EventFilterApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AggregateApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder(new Object[]{EventFilterApplication.class}, args)
            .from(EventFilterApplication.class)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

---

**2) EventFilterApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(EventFilterApplication.LiveProcessor.class)
public class EventFilterApplication {

    @Autowired
    LiveProcessor source;

    @StreamListener(LiveProcessor.INPUT)
    public void handle(byte[] event) {
        try {

            System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + ": event was processed:" + Arrays.toString(event));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Error={%s} on processing message=%s", e.getMessage(), Arrays.toString(event)));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EventFilterApplication.class, args);
    }

    interface LiveProcessor extends Source {

        String INPUT = "liveSource";

        @Input(INPUT)
        SubscribableChannel input();
    }
}
```

---

**3) application.yml**

```
spring:
cloud:
    stream:
        kafka:
          binder:
              brokers: kafka-broker.example.com:9092
              defaultBrokerPort: 9092
              defaultZkPort: 2181
              zkNodes: kafka-zookeeper.example.com
        type: kafka
        bindings:
            liveSource:
                binder: kafka
                consumer:
                    headerMode: raw
                    autoCommitOffset: true
                destination: topic_example_name
```

---

**4) build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext { springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE' }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

ext['logstashLogbackEncoderV'] = '4.8'
ext['springCloudV'] = 'Camden.SR1'
ext['springCloudStreamV'] = 'Brooklyn.SR2'
ext['springIntegrationKafkaV'] = '1.3.1.RELEASE'

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR1"
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-dependencies:Brooklyn.SR2"
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:spring-cloud-stream-app-dependencies:1.0.4.RELEASE"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion") {
            exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
            exclude group: 'log4j'
        }

        compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka")

        compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:$springIntegrationKafkaV") {
            exclude group: "org.slf4j"
        }

        compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:")

        compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")

        compile("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:${logstashLogbackEncoderV}")

        testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion") {
            exclude group: "org.slf4j"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplication is caused by `EventFilterApplication` as the parent root:

```
public class AggregateApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder(new Object[]{EventFilterApplication.class}, args)
            .from(EventFilterApplication.class)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

That is very likely to create two subscriptions. Instead of adding `EventFilterApplication` as root, you can simply do:

```
public class AggregateApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder(args)
            .from(EventFilterApplication.class)
            // rest of the pipeline
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

If you don't need to create an aggregate, this should be enough:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EventFilterApplication.class, args);
}
```

EDIT: added one extra example and clarified answer.

Comment: Actually i need aggregation to use several components of my application (together with EventFilterApplication).
The example was much simplified, there're also EventCheckerApplication and many others that are assebmled at AggregateApplication.

Comment: That's fine, but just don't add `EventFilterApplication` as the argument to `AggregateApplicationBuilder`

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it works. It remains to understand why is it so)